# jQuery onClick post data to second column

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, http-post

Can't figure it out what is the problem with the $.post here.
Actually i am retrieving data from database in column 1 and column 2. both are getting values perfectly when i am trying the controller function individually. Now, i am trying jquery that when the first column value will be clicked it shows the other column values. but its not passing on $.post

**Here is jquery :**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $('document').ready(function(){
     var link ="<?php echo base_url();?>" ;
        $( "#cat_level_1" ).on( "click", function() {
        var cat_level_1 = $('#cat_level_1').val();
        alert (cat_level_1);    //getting elements id like (men alert for 49) alert on click 
        $.post(link + "admin/admin_cat/cat_level_2", {cat_level_1 : cat_level_1}, function(data) {      
            alert( "Data Loaded: " + data);  
            //here it showing me HTML of my controller in alert.

            $('#cat_level_3').html('');
            $('#cat_level_4').html('');
            $('#cat_level_2').html(data);


        }); 
    });
    });
</script>
```

**For second column :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('document').ready(function(){
     var link ="<?php echo base_url();?>" ;
     $('#cat_level_2').click(function(){

        var cat_level_2 = $(this).val(); 
        alert (cat_level_2); //it shows me alert with its db id.
        $.post(link + "admin/admin_cat/cat_level_3", {cat_level_2:cat_level_1}, function(data) {

            $('#cat_level_4').html('');
            $('#cat_level_3').html(data);

         });
     });
});
<script>
```

**Here is my php(view) code from which i am getting values :**

**For column 1 :**

```
<div class="category-col">
    <select size="15" name="cat_level_1" id="cat_level_1">
    <?php
        if (isset($cat_level_1) && $cat_level_1 != ''){
            foreach ($cat_level_1 as $cat_1) {?>
                <option value="<?php echo $cat_1['cat_id']; ?>">
                   <?php echo $cat_1['cat_title']; ?>
                </option>
    <?php     }
        }
     ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

**For column 2 :**

```
<div class="category-col">
    <select size="15" name='cat_level_2' id='cat_level_2'>
    <?php
        if (isset($cat_level_2) && $cat_level_2 !=''){
            foreach ($cat_level_2 as $cat_2) {?>
                <option value="<?php echo $cat_2['cat_id']; ?>">
                   <?php echo $cat_2['cat_title']; ?>
                </option>
    <?php     }
        }
    ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Some one help me out please!. Where is the problem?
Thank you!

Comment: In your first column jquery. may be here is problem `{cat_level_1 : cat_level_1}` replace this code with: `{'cat_level_1' : cat_level_1}`. add the quotation mark for parameter.

Comment: now it wont showing me a popup with the id!

Answer (score 0):

The issues is in this line:

```
$.post(link + "admin/admin_cat/cat_level_3", {cat_level_1:cat_level_1}, function(data) {
```

The problem here is you are using var `"cat_level_1"` value in both the places and when trying to read the para in php you wont get it.

I think you should quote the key cat_level_1. so the code must be:

```
$.post(link + "admin/admin_cat/cat_level_3", {"cat_level_1":cat_level_1}, function(data) {
```

try this if it works for you.

Comment: wont affect anything. same output is there.. showing alert with the id popup  and then the html in popup

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line 
`var link ="<?php echo base_url();?>" ;` 
 you can not do this from javascript if you have virtual hosts set up you can do this `window.location.origin + "/admin/admin_cat/cat_level_2"`

Comment: if not have virtual hosts set up then any alternate ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok here could be the mistake.

> cat_level_2:cat_level_1

Make it

> cat_level_2:cat_level_2

in the second js.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot write php code inside js file.So this line will not work.

```
 var link ="<?php echo base_url();?>" ;
```

try to add this line inside your main view file (header) before you including the javascript files

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       var link ="<?php echo base_url();?>" ;
    </script>
```